# Android app not waking up from doze mode even with High priority Message

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-doze

I'm  trying to wake up my from doze mode using a Firebase High Priority Message. However, despite the high priority push being sent, my app is not reacting to this message and remains in doze mode. This has a direct and critical impact in the functionality of my app as I'm relying in this messages to notify users and have them interact with the app.

I also tried turning of batter optimizations for my App in Android Battery Settings and still app goes into doze mode after a long period of time. According to the documentation in:
https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby
We can the request to ignore battery optimizations in *AndroidManifest.xml* file but that  can lead to the app being banned from PlayStore if I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Is there any way I can ensure my app will wake up with the High priority message?

Here is my payload send to the device:

```
{
    "message": {
        "android": {
            "priority": "high",
            "ttl": "15s"
        },
        "data": {
            "reason": "",
            "ack": "true",
            "vibrate": "true",
            "language": "en",
            "type": "INCOMING_CALL",
            "title": "Caller",
            "roomId": "2lJ8VK0s6w5heGNmf3x1cnw3/3cO8A==",
            "callType": "GENERAL",
            
        },
        "token": "e-nwjbxum1Y:Ab4....."
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you got any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

FCM docs are really confusing. With the following setup, I was able to make it work at least 60% of the time in doze mode,

```
const options = {
        priority: "high",
        timeToLive: 0,
        ttl: 0,
        android: {
          priority: "high",
          timeToLive: 0,
          ttl: 0,
        }
      };

 admin.messaging()
        .sendToDevice(deviceFcmId, payload, options)
        .then(function (response) {})
        .catch(function (response) {
         
        });
```

Despite TTL value being 0, my device sometimes receives the message even after 5 minutes.